# C# Winforms How to link Checkbox with Button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, checkbox

I have two Events:

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Is it possible to link them so that when I press the button, the checkbox gets unchecked?

Answer (score 5):

In your button handler, you can simply set the `CheckBox.Checked` property to `false`:

```
checkBox1.Checked = false;
```

This will also call the `CheckedChange` handler of your `checkBox1`.